# Keep text visualizer open and continue debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

There is nice tool in Visual Studio 2008 called text visualizer which allows to visualize variables that contain some kind of text. In my program this is an OpenGL shader program that is being constructed at the run time. However text visualizer is a modal window and blocks all other actions, which includes stepping over the program, until closed.

Is there a way to continue to debug the program and keep the text visualizer open to be able to watch changes made to the text? Is there some free plugin that does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio Visualizer's architecture requires all Visualizers to be Modal windows, so the answer is No. Your best bet is to copy/paste the text into a diff tool.

Comment: That's stupid of Microsoft. I thought that this should be possible at least via plugins.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally not possible, but if you are a visualizer author there are a few options available. If you can render your view in HTML, you can then just show it in users internet browser.
Or you can start another process and transfer the data to that and have it show there:
http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/dialogdebuggervisualizershow-50864.aspx